# cant compare string returning function with a string

Tags: c++, function, class

I had made this function which is a member function of a class an the get function used in the this function is a function of another class which return string but when i am comparing it with a string so its not working i.e the if-statement is not executing

void printcarwheelstate()
{

```
  if(w.getwheelstate()=="Moving")
  {
      setcartomoving();

  cout<<"Wheel 1 is "<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Wheel 2 is "<<arr[1]<<endl;
     cout<<"Wheel 3 is "<<arr[2]<<endl;
      cout<<"Wheel 4 is "<<arr[3]<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
      setcartostopped();
      cout<<"Wheel 1 is "<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Wheel 2 is "<<arr[1]<<endl;
     cout<<"Wheel 3 is "<<arr[2]<<endl;
      cout<<"Wheel 4 is "<<arr[3]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: It seems odd that if wheel state is "Moving" the code starts the cart moving.

Comment: My guess: `getwheelstate` does not return a proper `std::string` but `char const *` or `char *`, a.k.a a C-style-string. Then you would be comparing pointers, not string contents. We need a [mre] to be sure.

Comment: Please show us how `getwheelstate()` is implemented because that function is related to the question. We don't care about 8 lines of `cout`.

Comment: @churill class wheel
{
private:
    string state;
public:
    void setwheelstate(string s)
    {
        state=s;
    }
    string getwheelstate()
    {
        return state;
    }
};

Comment: @HamzaKhan Thanks for the update. Please [edit] your question to include this information. Btw: what's `string`? Is it `std::string`? I've seen people typedef weird things as `string`, so just to make sure.

Comment: If `getwheelstate` `std::string` your code works as intended and you simply have a typo in the state-name. You should prefer enums here.

Answer (score 0):

I have write the code for it. Its 100% functional.

> Code is Here

```
    #include<iostream>

#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class State {
    
    string state ="";
    public:
     void setwheelstate( string state){
        this->state  =state;
        
    }
        string getwheelstate(){
       return   this->state ;
        
    }
    
};

int main ()
{
    int arr[5]= {1,3,4,5,6};
    State state;
    state.setwheelstate("Moving");// you can also use this "if" statement
   // if ( state.getwheelstate().compare("Moving") == 0); 
    if(state.getwheelstate()=="Moving")
  {
     // setcartomoving();
  cout<<" IF Statement"<<endl;
  cout<<"Wheel 1 is "<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Wheel 2 is "<<arr[1]<<endl;
     cout<<"Wheel 3 is "<<arr[2]<<endl;
      cout<<"Wheel 4 is "<<arr[3]<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
     // setcartostopped();
     
  cout<<" Else Statement"<<endl;
      cout<<"Wheel 1 is "<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Wheel 2 is "<<arr[1]<<endl;
     cout<<"Wheel 3 is "<<arr[2]<<endl;
      cout<<"Wheel 4 is "<<arr[3]<<endl;
  }
    
    
}
```

> Output of this code is:

[image]

**Hope its work for you. If still you are facing problem then there is a logical error not syntax**

Answer (score -1):

try printing w.getwheelstate() to see what it returns.
have you checked capital and small case letters? because there is a deference between them in comparing strings and their ascii code are different.

also you can try this:

```
tmp = w.getwheelstate().compare("Moving")
if (tmp == 0)
{
//body
}
```